# javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert .. to class java.lang.Long

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, seam

I am working currently with JSF and JBoss. When I try to debug my application remotely I get the following:

```
javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert pro.entity.SysLangresource@3da91823 of type class pro.entity.SysLangresource_$$_javassist_41 to class java.lang.Long
```

I can not recognize particularly where is the error.

`SysLangresource` class:

```
package pro.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;

import org.hibernate.validator.Length;
import org.hibernate.validator.NotNull;

import EntityMain;

@Entity
@Table(name = "SYS_LANGRESOURCE")
public class SysLangresource extends EntityMain {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7867388773892723774L;
private static final String KEY = "LARE";

private long lareId;
private String lareName;

@Override
public void insertData() { //       
}
@Override
public void updateData() { //       
}

@Id
@TableGenerator(name=SEQU + KEY, table=SEQU_TABLE, pkColumnName=SEQU_PK, pkColumnValue=SEQU + KEY, valueColumnName=SEQU_VALUE, allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = SEQU + KEY)
@Column(name = "LARE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 18, scale = 0)
@NotNull
public long getLareId() {
    return lareId;
}
public void setLareId(long lareId) {
    this.lareId = lareId;
}

@Column(name = "LARE_NAME", length = 50)
@Length(max = 50)
public String getLareName() {
    return lareName;
}
public void setLareName(String lareName) {
    this.lareName = lareName;
}

}
```

The stacktrace:

```
      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert at.prosigma.profiler.entity.SysLangresource@7b0cfc3f of type class at.prosigma.profiler.entity.SysLangresource_$$_javassist_41 to class java.lang.Long
    at org.jboss.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToNumber(ELSupport.java:271)
    at org.jboss.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:331)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:322)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:274)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.getValue(AstMethodSuffix.java:59)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:67)
    at org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:173)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:320)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:200)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:836)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:281)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:279)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractRowsRenderer.encodeCellChildren(AbstractRowsRenderer.java:288)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractTableRenderer.encodeOneRow(AbstractTableRenderer.java:387)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractRowsRenderer.process(AbstractRowsRenderer.java:83)
    at at.prosigma.jsf.components.dataTable.PagedTableDataModel.walk(PagedTableDataModel.java:232)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.walk(UIDataAdaptor.java:1133)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractRowsRenderer.encodeRows(AbstractRowsRenderer.java:104)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractRowsRenderer.encodeRows(AbstractRowsRenderer.java:88)
    at at.prosigma.jsf.components.dataTable.PagedDataTableRenderer.encodeTBody(PagedDataTableRenderer.java:419)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractTableRenderer.encodeChildren(AbstractTableRenderer.java:97)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:812)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:886)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:892)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:137)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:812)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:279)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:220)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:215)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:812)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:271)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:117)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:812)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:886)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:892)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:592)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:144)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:245)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:510)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:38)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:73)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:58)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at at.prosigma.profiler.filter.DownloadFilter.doFilter(DownloadFilter.java:176)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: In which class the error is generated? Show the usage of this entity

Comment: I think this line causes the error: Column(name = "LARE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 18, scale = 0)

Comment: @ rookieB : this the problem I could not know the exact class, but the mentioned class in my question is used as the following:       SysLangresource lr = new SysLangresource(); 
new SysLangresourceAccess().persist(lr);
SysLanguages l = new SysLanguages(0, new SysLangresourceAccess().retrieve(Long.valueOf(lr.getLareId())), langText, new BdbBasicdataAccess().retrieve(language));
persist(l);
return Long.valueOf(lr.getLareId());

Comment: Do you have the problem only when remote debugging or always? It seems to be totally Hibernate-JPA related.

Comment: @ Dylan Meeus : shall I change the value of some attribute?

Comment: @Kalathoki: please stop formatting non-code as code. Library/framework/product names like "JSF" and "JBoss" are not code!

Comment: @Kalathoki: Highlighting? You were formatting them as code using backticks! If you really need to highlight, use bold of italics, but even then this is completely unnecessary here. The keywords are already present in tags.

Comment: @Kalathoki: Fine. For now please stop suggesting edits until you have read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted from top to bottom, including the links, so that you understand how it's interpreted from the other side on.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you pasted stacktrace. You want us to read the tea leaves? :)

Comment: @Henryk Konsek : please have a look, I have edited my post. Now you can see the stack trace

Comment: @user2034269 The problem most likely appears to be in your view. Where is the affected xhtml file?